# Input text shrinks after entering details into the field

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my contact form. Every time when I enter some details into the input text field (where you usually fill up your name), it shrinks down by a bit when i start to enter details into the email field after.

May I know why it's doing such a thing. I know i have a border of 1 pixel declared into the input element, but that shouldn't disturb the field after there is value inside right?

Would appreciate some help on this.

```
Code:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/24G6z/1/

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: I have attached my code together with the question.

Comment: Post your code **in your question**.

Comment: I did, it's been added as a JFiddle, so you can see what is going on with the contact form. Thanks

Comment: When you say that it happens when you enter something... Are you referring to when you click it, when you are in the act of entering text into it, or after you have entered text in it?

Comment: After I have entered text in the name field and move on to the next field to fill up, which in this case is the email field, the name field sort of shrinks down in size by a pixel or so.

Comment: That would most likely be the hover.  Since you have the border set to 1 pixel when the element is hovered on, moving the mouse away into another text field would change the border back to original.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the hover problem (didnt notice there was a hover floating around input text), but the problem is now tied to the input field itself. everytime when i type in something in the text field and then type something else in the email field, the text field shrinks again.

Comment: This is what is causing the problem: `input:focus[type="text"] { border:0;`.  If you remove the `border:0;`, it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is with

```
input:focus { 
     border:0;
}
```

because your email field has a special selector for it (see below), it doesn't experience any border change (and no glitch)

```
input[type="email"] {
    border:0
}
```

However, your name field has a border:1px solid #58B9FA applied to it. When the user focuses on it, that border is removed (because of the :focus selector) and you get that jerky motion.

Hope it helps!

Comment: if i do remove the border of 1 pixel, there's like a weird kind of border appears around the text field in which I don't know how to remove. Please help me to solve this issue, with or without removing the border of 1pixels. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Jeiman you should be able to do that by just setting `border:0` instead. Otherwise, just remove the `input:focus` rule. That would fix it as well.